# Why won't Minecraft Magical Crops stay planted?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I've tried planting Earth Seeds and Minicio Seeds on Fertilized Dirt, and every time they stay planted only for a few seconds before the seed pops off the ground. This happens even right next to a glowstone block (light level 13):

[image: plant screenshot]

Vanilla seeds like potatoes and carrots grow just fine.

Running Magical Crops: Core 4.0.0_PUBLIC_BETA_4b and Magical Crops: Decorative 4.0.0_PUBLIC_BETA_4a in Minecraft 1.7.10 (Project Ozone 2 Reloaded mod pack).

Comment: Huh. Maybe it can't grow in that biome? Besides that I've really got nothing else. (Or maybe  it being able to reach sunlight, but I digress.)

Comment: Does this happen with other types of seeds? Does it happen in different places?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you have to use Agricraft (sticks and trimmers etc) for almost every plantable in that pack (with a few exceptions).